# Timeout when retrieving results from Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

This query for retrieving movie posters from Wikidata results in "Query timeout limit reached" errors on query.wikidata.org:

```
#defaultView:ImageGrid
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?pic ?fileTitle ?width ?height
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q11424 .
  ?item wdt:P3383 ?pic .
  BIND(STRAFTER(wikibase:decodeUri(STR(?pic)), "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/") AS ?fileTitle)

  SERVICE wikibase:label { 
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" 
  }

  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "commons.wikimedia.org";
                    wikibase:api "Generator";
                    wikibase:limit "once";
                    mwapi:generator "allpages";
                    mwapi:gapfrom ?fileTitle;
                    mwapi:gapnamespace 6; # NS_FILE
                    mwapi:gaplimit 1;
                    mwapi:prop "imageinfo";
                    mwapi:iiprop "dimensions".
    ?size wikibase:apiOutput "imageinfo/ii/@size".
    ?width wikibase:apiOutput "imageinfo/ii/@width".
    ?height wikibase:apiOutput "imageinfo/ii/@height".
  }

}
ORDER BY ?item
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0
```

Setting a low limit works, with fewer than 100 results, and removing `ORDER BY`. However, `ORDER BY` is necessary to ensure that subsequent queries retrieve all results, and adding `ORDER BY ?item` throws a timeout error again. Ideally, I would like to filter by posters with a minimum width, but adding `FILTER(?width>1500)` times out no matter how low the limit.

Any suggestions for optimising the query to work consistently and reliably? Even if it only returns a single value, the query can be repeated until all values have been retrieved.

Comment: https://w.wiki/nx$

Comment: @StanislavKralin this doesn't look correct? Your subquery doesn't return `?fileTitle` var we should be used for the mwapi.  Or what is the magic behind your query? As far as I understand, the mwapi returns width and height for a given filename? Also he does want to use pagination for which at least theoretically `order by` is needed.

Comment: @UninformedUser, yes, my error. https://w.wiki/n$9

Comment: nice. but ... nitpick: a small typo in the view pragma which breaks the gridview: `#defaultVew:ImageGrid` -> `#defaultView:ImageGrid`

Comment: Thanks @stanislav-kralin, the second one works perfectly!